# (Chrome DevTools) querySelector Returns null even though Element Clearly Exists on Page

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, phantomjs, casperjs

I am trying to scrape a website using CasperJS, but the `casper.waitForSelector()` function always times out, meaning it never finds the given element which I need.

Then I did these steps in Google Chrome:

1. Open the web page and Chrome DevTools Console.
2. Wait for the element to be visible on the page to my eyes.
3. Type in the console: `document.querySelector(".dropdown-menu")`.
4. Chrome gives `null` (*element does not exist*).

But, when I switch to the Elements (DevTools), and then click on the needed element in Inspect Element Mode (or one of its children), Chrome returns the element in the console with the same `document.querySelector(".dropdown-menu")` command.

I am suspecting the page has invalid HTML code (unclosed tags).

When I click on the element in Inspect Element Mode, Chrome fixes the HTML DOM, meaning JavaScript now returns the element as expected.

If this is true, is there anything I can do in **CasperJS** to trigger the same DOM-fixing event?

If this is not true, what can it possibly be?

Comment: Could you post the page in question so we have a [MCVE] to work with?

Comment: I'm afraid I can't. The website is private and requires login. I would gladly post it if this wasn't the case.

Comment: If you can't post the site, might you be able to copy the HTML that reproduces the problem? Kind of hard to solve problems without being able to see where the problem is

Comment: Browsers do fix up invalid HTML, but they do it when the page is loaded, not when you open the Elements tab.

Comment: Maybe you should use an HTML validator to try to find problems in your structure.

Comment: HTML validator didn't give any error.

Comment: I believe I found the problem. The main content container on the website is actually an iframe from another website. After running a code in Chrome Console, I can actually reach the elements inside the iframe. I will test it tomorrow with casperjs, and if successful, I will post the code.

Comment: Be sure to use screenshots for debugging. CasperJS is very different from Chrome and very old. Your page could just be not working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per your [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51294732/chrome-devtools-queryselector-returns-null-even-though-element-clearly-exists#comment89568200_51294732), since the element is in an `iframe`, you can access the element using [`casper.withFrame()`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#withframe):

```
casper.withFrame('frame_1', function () {
  var dropdown_menu = this.getElementInfo('.dropdown-menu');

  this.echo(dropdown_menu.html);
});
```

Alternatively, you can switch your current main frame scope using one of the following  functions:

- [`casper.switchToFrame()`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#switchtoframe)
- [`casper.switchToMainFrame()`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#switchtomainframe)
- [`casper.switchToParentFrame()`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#switchtoparentframe)

Or, you can even access the existing PhantomJS WebPage instance via [`page`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#page) and call one of the underlying PhantomJS methods for frame navigation:

- [`casper.page.switchToChildFrame()`](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/method/switch-to-child-frame.html)
- [`casper.page.switchToFocusedFrame()`](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/method/switch-to-focused-frame.html)
- [`casper.page.switchToFrame()`](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/method/switch-to-frame.html)
- [`casper.page.switchToMainFrame()`](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/method/switch-to-main-frame.html)
- [`casper.page.switchToParentFrame()`](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/method/switch-to-parent-frame.html)